# Proving stability of F1 metric for a given sample size

Tags: classification, confidence-interval, resampling, f1, sampling-distribution

Okay so say you have sequence classification problem: extracting entities from conversations. Say one of the labels is CITIES.

Say you have calculated P/R/f1/support for CITIES and it looks like this:

| P | R | F1 | Support |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .89 | .90 | .89 | 93 |

Where 93 is number of positive cases of CITIES (TP + FN) in the test set, which occur across 50 documents.

Now say you have to convince your team that the sample size is sufficient to trust these results? How does one "prove" this statistically?

My intuition was to create a number of buckets for sample size like:

`samples_sizes = [1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50]`

let `K` = the number of times I sample from my test set at `sample_sizes[i]`

let `N` = the current sample size of `sample_sizes[i]`

where `i` is the current iteration count of the following loop:

For each bucket size `N`:

1. I take a random sample of `N` documents `K` times, and calculate the F1 scores on those samples, and store the avg.

At the end of these loops i have list of avg F1 scores ranging across my `sample_sizes`.

If I make a plot with the x axis being sample size, and y axis is the avg F1, I get a curve that looks more or less like this (K=1 in the image):
[image]

My question is, is pointing to where the curve starts to converge at an F1 score enough to show that the sample size is sufficient to trust the F1 metric? Are the stats nerds at work going to give me a hard time about this?